# Excel VBA Validate Automated Email Status

Tags: vba, email, excel

I have been looking around the net to no avail thus far. I have an Excel spreadsheet with associated VBA code which, at a certain time everyday, e-mails the contents of the workbook to other people in the company I work for.

This code is in an infinite loop, and is rarely closed. We have it setup on one computer to do this all day to calculate and update various things on our intranet. There are a few workbooks the code accesses at different times everyday using a time delay function.

The problem is that sometimes the code runs a little fast and ends up sending two emails of the same workbook instead of one. Refer to the code below:

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernal32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Do While 1
Start = Timer

If Hour(Now())=13 & Minute(Now())>=45 Then
s = "path to file"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:=s
ActiveWorkbook.SendMail Recipients:="someone@someone.com"
ActiveWindow.Close
End If

delay = Int(600 - (Timer - Start))
If delay>0 Then
delay = delay * 1000
Sleep delay
End If
Loop

End Sub
```

As I said, there are more workbooks that are activated and calculations are done on them but there's no need to put that code up as well. It all follows pretty much the same format as above.

I think if I played around with the sleep settings in the loop I could get it to only email once but that would take too much time.

I was considering using a simple if statement to check to see if an email was sent today (using Date?) and if so, simply close the active window else send an email. This would ensure that only one email would be sent per day per workbook. The only trouble I am having is how to code that exactly...

There's not much online that I could find in regards to documentation about the SendMail addin that we are using. Everything I try comes up with an error and I have no idea how to work around this. An example of what I have tried was:

```
If SendMail = False Then
"send the email"
Else
"close"
```

Obviously that wouldn't work but it was worth the try.

So if anyone can give me a hand with this, it would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Which email client do u use? Outlook?

Comment: One last question... You need to send the email at 1:45PM or is there some other criteria?

Comment: For that one report, it needs to be sent between 1:45PM - 1:59PM. There are four other reports that are sent at different times but have a 14min range like above.

Comment: Perfect. Gimme some time... I have a theory which I would like to test before posting :)

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you for taking the time to help :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37542/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-scott-fiander)

Comment: Wow! Don't you think you accepted the answer too fast :P Were you able to test it so soon?

Comment: I tested it and changed a few things to accommodate the times I needed and which workbooks needed to send emails and which didn't. Works like a charm!! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Damn! you are fast! I took approx 20 mins to run and test the code :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the time slots that you are using but I guess the problem is that the delay is not good enough and hence you are getting the email twice.

Here is a code that I tried and tested. I am using a slightly different method than yours wherein I am latebinding with Outlook and sending the excel file as an attachment. The benefit of this method is that you don't have to **open the workbook**.

**Test Conditions**

```
'Based on your comment, Testing for 4 different workbooks
'for 4 diff time intervals
'Time interval 1 : 11:30 PM - 11:35PM     C:\Temp\Book1.xlsx
'Time interval 2 : 11:35 PM - 11:40PM     C:\Temp\Book2.xlsx
'Time interval 3 : 11:40 PM - 11:45PM     C:\Temp\Book3.xlsx
'Time interval 4 : 11:45 PM - 11:50PM     C:\Temp\Book4.xlsx
```

**Logic**

The logic is to set the `Wait` value in such a way that it doesn't re-enter the same loop again. Also it helps if you specify the start time and the end time in the `IF` condition unlike in your code where you specify just the start time.

I have commented the code so that you will not have a problem understanding the code. Still if you do, simply post back.

**Code**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim B1 As String, B2 As String, B3 As String, B4 As String
    Dim sEmail As String
    Dim SendEml As Boolean

    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object

    'Testing for 4 different workbooks for 4 diff time intervals
    'Time interval 1 : 11:30 PM - 11:35PM     C:\Temp\Book1.xlsx
    'Time interval 2 : 11:35 PM - 11:40PM     C:\Temp\Book2.xlsx
    'Time interval 3 : 11:40 PM - 11:45PM     C:\Temp\Book3.xlsx
    'Time interval 4 : 11:45 PM - 11:50PM     C:\Temp\Book4.xlsx

    B1 = "C:\Temp\Book1.xlsx"
    B2 = "C:\Temp\Book2.xlsx"
    B3 = "C:\Temp\Book3.xlsx"
    B4 = "C:\Temp\Book4.xlsx"

    '~~> Email Address
    sEmail = "someone@someone.com"

    Do
        Select Case Hour(Now())
            '~~> I have only one case here as I am checking for 11PM
            '~~> If your time slots fall under differnt hours then
            '~~> Create more cases accordingly
            Case 23
                If Minute(Now()) >= 20 And Minute(Now()) < 25 Then
                    FileToAttach = B1: SendEml = True
                ElseIf Minute(Now()) >= 25 And Minute(Now()) < 30 Then
                    FileToAttach = B2: SendEml = True
                ElseIf Minute(Now()) >= 30 And Minute(Now()) < 35 Then
                    FileToAttach = B3: SendEml = True
                ElseIf Minute(Now()) >= 35 And Minute(Now()) < 40 Then
                    FileToAttach = B4: SendEml = True
                End If
        End Select

        '~~> Latebind with Outlook to send the email
        If SendEml = True Then
            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .To = sEmail
                .Subject = "SO Example"
                .Body = "Hi Scott :)"
                .Attachments.Add FileToAttach '<~~ This is where we attach the file
                .Send
            End With
            SendEml = False
        End If

        '~~> I have set the wait time for 200 seconds which is about 3.3 mins
        '~~> Change as applicable. You have to ensure that you set this carefully
        '~~> So that the Do Loop doesn't run in the same time frame else you will
        '~~> get duplicate emails.
        Wait 200
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```